# How to configure what certificates can be issued using Web Enrollment in Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, certificate-authority, ad-certificate-services

I have a CA installed on of my Windows Servers in a small farm of systems.  I've installed the Certification Authority Web Enrollment and Certificate Enrollment Web Service roles on the CA.

I want to issue a Computer certificate to a computer not jointed to my domain.  The user attempting web enrollment has domain credentials.

The user was able to navigate to https://myServerHostname/certsrv and request a User certificate successfully.

However, the user needs a Computer cert as well.  From the certsrv site, the user tried the following:

- Advanced Certificate Request
- Create and Submit a Request to this CA

However, the Computer certificate template is not available under the Certificate Template heading.  He is only seeing "User" and "Basic EFS".

How do I configure the CA to allow him to request a Computer cert for his system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Customizing the Certificate Services Web Enrollment Pages"
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381929(v=vs.85).aspx

Following these instructions, I was able to configure what certificates are available via Web Enrollment.